# Javascript onDrop attribute not assigned

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop

I encountered a wierd problem in javascript. I tried to create a div box in which i could drop other divs. Strangely the onDrop-attribute doesn't get assigned to the div allthough if I read it, it seems to have it. Where is my error here?
Here's a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ballowii/fdhw3ods/)

```
    function creatLeftRightTree(parentElement){
            var leftTree = document.createElement("DIV");
            var rightTree = document.createElement("DIV");

            leftTree.id="leftTree";
            rightTree.id="rightTree";
            leftTree.className="dndcontainer";
            rightTree.className="dndcontainer";


            leftTree.onDrop="drop(event)";
            rightTree.onDrop="drop(event)";

            rightTree.ondragover="allowDrop(event)";

            parentElement.appendChild(leftTree);
            parentElement.appendChild(rightTree);
            rightTree.innerHTML+= rightTree.onDrop;
            //it must not be possible to drop in the left Tree

        }
         function drop(ev) {
        ev.preventDefault();
        var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
        var dropTarget = ev.target;
                dropTarget.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
        }

function allowDrop(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }

function drag(ev) {
            ev.preventDefault();
        }
creatLeftRightTree(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0]);
```

EDIT: Updated fiddle and code for less confusion. I wrote an alternativ function called drop(event). Doesn't really matter though, cause the problem is: it doesn't change the onDrop-Attribute

[image: This here is the problem, this div should have the attribute]

Comment: Setting properties doesn't affect attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript event handlers are all-lowercase; you mean `ondrop`.

Also, do not assign strings; you should assign the function directly:

```
leftTree.ondrop = drop;
```

Comment: Can you post a fiddle ? Cause if i change that, the only difference is, that the read out is undefined and if you inspect the div, it still doesn't have the ondrop-attribute.